# How could I add an ico to my exe with CLion?

Tags: c++, clion, ico

I want to add an ico to the exe when it's built. You know, the default icon is really ugly and boring.

I just started using CLion, and I searched the Internet for a long time but couldn't find the correct way, including adding .rc file, modifying CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: What is your target platform? It's highly dependent on the target OS. Also please [edit] your question to show us your resource file and the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.